# How to get a list of files to the template in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

New to meteor, I'm having a hell of a time with the whole client/server thing. Super fun.

I want to read a list of all files that are in a folder, and just print them on the UI, on a template. It has to be possible. Here's the code.

js file:

```
var availableFiles = [];
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    availableFiles = fs.readdirSync(process.env.PWD + '/public/uploads');
    console.log(availableFiles);
}

Router.map(function() {

    this.route('home', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'home',
        data: {files: availableFiles}
    });
});
```

html file:

```
<template name="home">
{{#each data.files}}
    {{this}}
{{/each}}
</template>
```

I've tried to put the fs calls inside a function on data on the route definition, but I get "Npm is not defined" errors. I don't know if that's how it should be structured or not, remember, newb here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reading from a directory inside of your app's root dir is really tricky (and asked about all the time). The problem is that when you deploy, the directory structure will change. Anyway, a better solution to this problem is to write to a collection whenever a user uploads something. Then you can just read the collection instead of the directory.

Comment: I actually get away of the issue by using the process.env.PWD variable, and get the proper directory that way. I'm not uploading through this app, the files are rather large and placed on the "uploads" (terribly named) folder for processing. I also don't want to have to write a single list to the database every time the files change or something, that would be a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably do this with a reactive array (http://reactivearray.meteor.com/) and a Meteor method.  Something like:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    Meteor.methods({
        getFiles() {
            return fs.readdirSync(process.env.PWD + '/public/uploads');
        }
    });
}

if( Meteor.isClient ) {
    Template.home.onCreated( function() {
        Template.instance().files = new ReactiveArray();
        Meteor.call('getFiles', function(error, result) {
            if( error ) {
                console.log( error );
            } else {
                Template.instance().files = files.concat( result );
            }
        });
    });
    Template.home.helpers({
        files() {
            return Template.instance().files.array();
        }
    });
}

Router.map(function() {

    this.route('home', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'home',
        data: {files: availableFiles}
    });
});
```

Syntax might not be perfect, but that should get the point across.  You'll also need to change your template to {{#each files}}